# How to tell if current OS uses Linux-like or MacOSX-like shared libraries?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, shared-libraries

I am aware that there are (at least) two radically different kinds of shared-library files on Unix-type systems. One is the kind used on GNU/Linux systems and probably other systems as well (with the filename ending in ".so") and the other used in Mac OS X, and also *possibly* other systems as well (with the filename ending in ".dylib").

My question is this --- is there any type of test I could do from a shell-script that would easily detect *which* of these two paradigms the current OS uses for shared libraries?

I'm sure I could find some way to easily deal with this variance --- if only I knew of a simple test I could run from a shell-script that would tell me which type of shared library is used on the current system.

Comment: You could start with the output of `uname -a` or the contents of `/etc/issue`.  Also, keep in mind that OS X is (more or less) BSD, not Linux, so even if you link against the right libraries, you're not going to have binary compatibility if you just forklift from one system to another.

Comment: Identifying the system isn't the problem --- the problem is knowing what type of shared library the system uses. I could do the "uname -a" as you suggest -- or get an even more parceable ID-code for the system by running GNU's "config-guess" script (I can't look at "/etc/issue" 'coz that doesn't exist on my system) -- but unless there's a handy way of looking up the library format based on the identification of the system, I'm still at square one.

Comment: @shellter FreeBSD (and other BSD variants, I guess) has its own Linux-compatibility layer on top of BSD kernel which allows to run unmodified Linux (ELF) binaries. Once upon a time they had DOOM and Java that way :) Besides Wikipedia tells that Linux can run MacOS X 10.6 binaries as well. So the question is what exactly user3080003 wants :)

Comment: did you look at the code in "config-guess"? That seems like your best hope. (Other stuff about binary formats removed. Thanks @user3159253 for the feedback, I learned something today.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess you need to check filetypes of executables on a target platform. You may use `file` for that (check its output for, say, `/bin/ls` ). `ELF` is a most widely used executable type on Linux, while `Mach-O` is "natively" used in MacOS X.

A note: technically there're other executable types on these systems, say `a.out` and `PEF`, and, you guess, those formats have their own dynamic libraries. Frankly speaking Linux has a pluggable support for executable formats and even `Win32 .EXEs` may be executed "quasi-natively" in Linux (of course, they need an implementation of Win32 API working above a given kernel API, WINE is a such implemetation).

Also if you need to *create* a dynamically loaded library, then you should use one of those portable build systems (to name a few: GNU autotools, CMake, QMake...). Thus you'll get not only ordinary DLL extension but also linker flags, portable methods of installation/uninstallation and so on...

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) Of course, I have reasons for not using GNU autotools -- namely that *none* of the well-known packages prepared by other people with autotools could I successfully build on my android - while my own stuff built without a hitch -- but what you told me about using the "file" command solved my problem. :-) I wrote a command that parses the output of "file", and now everything is fine. :-) Thanks. :-)